# Printing a byte array to thermal printer Java

Tags: java, zebra-printers

I am using java application to make web service call to FedEx and trying to print the label to a local USB connected thermal printer.
I will get byte array from FedEx as response and want to print this to client machine where the thermal printer connected

```
DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

PrintService ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(image, DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE, das);    
job.print(doc, pras);
```

Your help is highly appreciated, or suggest me/redirect me to a link where I can find solution.

**UPDATE:** I want to Print the FedEx label onto a locally USB connected thermal printer from a web based application.

I have the server code written as above, I am facing issue to print the label locally.

The above code is looking for a printer connected on the application server.

When client is clicking on "Print Label" button, the FedEx webservice call is success and returning the ZPLII format byte array correctly but **"want to push this byte array to client machine and print to the thermal Printer"**.

Only until getting the byte array back from FedEx is working after that nothing I could able to implement to bring the byte array back to printer to print on thermal printer.

Comment: you show code, but you don't tell what the expected output is or why that code is wrong or what it actually does, is the internet in general mindreaders?

Comment: Jarrod. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: You still don't actually say what isn't working, what is wrong or anything other than here is a blob of code and what I am doing.

Comment: Bringing the byte array from FedEx till app server is working after that I cannot proceed how to implement sending this byte array from server to the local printer to print. At-least now?

Comment: I am trying this option http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/ if someone has used this before, please let me know, if someone implemented for the problem which suits me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [jZebra](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra) for printing this to a local USB connected thermal printer

Here is my code goes.

In Action class

```
byte[] imageArr = ShipmentReply.getImage();
out = ServletActionContext.getResponse().getOutputStream();
out.write(imageArr);
out.flush();
```

In jQuery

```
$.post("printFedexLabel", function(imageArr){
    printZebra(imageArr);
});
```

In JSP

```
<applet name="jZebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jzebra.jar" width="1" height="1">
     <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function printZebra(data) {
       var applet = document.jZebra;
       if (applet != null) {
          applet.append(data);
          applet.print();
    }
   }
</script>
```

Thats it.... it worked awesome. Please let me know if someone need help in any further information on this implementation.

Comment: I am unable to find "jzebra.jar", can any one please help me on this. When I tried to download 'jzebra.jar' it showing application. I just want to print pdf and I m working on spring. How to resolve this issue. Please help me on this.

Comment: For this we have to configure complete jzebra application. But I want to use just as plugin to download 2 or 3 files and can run.