# Javascript arrayofbyte alternative?

Tags: javascript, arrays, byte, thermal-printer

So I'm trying to do a simple task of printing bold text to an external printer.

In Android, this is done as follows,

```
    byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 27, 33, 0 };
    byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

    format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
    os.write(format);

    os.write( string.getBytes());

    format[2] = ((byte)(arrayOfByte1[2]));
    os.write(format);
```

Which I believe is BOLD_ON + string + BOLD_OFF.

Now in Javascript, I have no idea how to write the equivalent.

The best I've managed is below, only the bold works and it doesn't turn off.

```
var lines = [];
    lines.push("\x1b\x40"); // Init
    lines.push("\x1b\x21\x00"); // Normal
    lines.push("This is normal text\n");
    lines.push("\x1b\x45\x01"); // Bold On
    lines.push("This is bold text\n");
    lines.push("\x1b\x45\x00"); // Bold Off
    lines.push("\x1b\x35"); // Italic On
    lines.push("This is italic text\n");
    lines.push("\x1b\x34"); // Italic Off

        for (let index = 0; index < lines.length; index++) 
        {
             printer.write(lines[i]);
        }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you're looking for [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely not sure if this going to work, but can you send these bytes to the printer?

```
var esc = "\u001B",
    lines = [
    ESC + "@",
    ESC + "E\u0001",
    ESC + "E\0"
];
function getBinaryRep(lines,joiner = "\n"){
    lines = lines.join(joiner);
    var blob = new Blob([lines],{type:"text/plain"}),
        reader = new FileReader;
    return new Promise(function(res,rej){
        reader.onload = function(){
            res(Array.from(new Uint8Array(this.result)));
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
}

var x= getBinaryRep(lines);
x.then((x)=>console.log(x)); //[27, 64, 10, 27, 69, 1, 10, 27, 69, 0]
```

Inside the `then` instead of console.logging send them to the printer to see what comes out.

Comment: rgument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | ArrayLike<number> | SharedArrayBuffer'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer | ArrayLike<number> | SharedArrayBuffer'.

Comment: I am running the script on the console, perfectly, you are doing something wrong here. First of all it is impossible for you to get an array buffer ok? Because it is converted to normal one within the then handler. You also do not mention where you get this error.

Comment: This might as well help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481390/printing-a-byte-array-to-thermal-printer-java